# Fabric/Firebase Crashlytics API

Tags: firebase, jira, crashlytics, google-fabric

I'm aware that there isn't a Fabric/Crashlytics API that I can use to pull data.  I'm wondering if when the move happens to Firebase/Crashlytics will there be some sort of official API that we can use to get crash statistics?

I am trying to create Jiras upon a crash but our jira locally hosted and isn't publicly available so I can't integrate it through the service hooks provided.

Answer (score 1):

Mike from Firebase and Fabric here. We support JIRA server instances. However if it is not accessible to us, for example behind a firewall, then we don't have any integrations that will work.

Comment: Hi Mike.  Thanks for the reply.  Yes, our jira server is behind a firewall and isn't publicly available so this is why I was inquiring about future plans for a Firebase API that we can use to pull Crashlytics data. I looked over the current Firebase API but didn't see any Crashlytics specifics.  Thanks again.

Comment: Gotcha, no plans at the moment.

Comment: @MikeBonnell Is there any documentation link about integration with JIRA?

Comment: Yep, it's here: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9118259?hl=en

Comment: @MikeBonnell Hello! Is it possible to find out ip addresses that firebase use for Jira integration? Our Jira instance is behind a firewall too and we want to add exception rule for firebase addresses

Comment: No, the IP addresses change too frequently to be reliable to use for this purpose.

Comment: @MikeBonnell is this still the case do you know? No way to get the IP address that Firebase uses in the Jira integration?

Comment: @KesWalker I have absolutely no idea. I haven't worked on Firebase for several years. The support team should be able to help with a more recent and relevant answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Analytics Data API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1) can be used to retrieve the crashAffectedUsers & crashFreeUsersRate. crashAffectedUsers is number of users that logged a crash, and crashFreeUsersRate number of users without crash events divided by the total number of users. The [Data API schema page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema) contains more details about these metrics.

An example request to the [RunReport](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/runReport) method looks like the following:

```
{
  "dateRanges": [
    {
      "startDate": "7daysAgo",
      "endDate": "today"
    }
  ],
  "dimensions": [
    {
      "name": "date"
    }
  ],
  "metrics": [
    {
      "name": "crashFreeUsersRate"
    },
    {
      "name": "crashAffectedUsers"
    },
    {
      "name": "totalUsers"
    }
  ]
}
```

An example response row looks like the following. This row means: on 2021-11-13, the crash free users rate was 99.836%, 2 users were affected by crashes, and 1220 total users used your app.

```
    {
      "dimensionValues": [
        {
          "value": "20211113"
        }
      ],
      "metricValues": [
        {
          "value": "0.99836"
        },
        {
          "value": "2"
        },
        {
          "value": "1220"
        }
      ]
    },
```